# deploy a gwt application into jboss AS7

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jboss, jboss7.x, war

When I'm trying to deploy my gwt application (which I transformed 
to a web dynamic project) I got this error :

```
23:46:11,559 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TestWar.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TestWar.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "TestWar.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl' not found
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:555)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deployPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:295)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

I am not using any persistence, and I don't need to use it.
Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your gwt application has created, you may be select `Use Google App Engine`. Because of it, there were files created like `persistence.xml' etc.

If you want simple gwt application, Don't tick on `Use Google App Engine` option.